# How to make a PS file form a TeX document with graphics ?

Tags: compiling, graphics, ps

Could someone explain me how to generate a PS file from a TeX file. I have included some graphics in my TeX file.
I used graphicx package.

I am using TeXLive

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unless I misunderstood the question, I think something along the following lines should give you a PS file:

```
latex sample2e.tex
dvips sample2e.dvi
```

(The `sample2e.tex` was slightly modified by adding `\usepackage{graphicx}` in the preamble, and inserting a sample image with `\includegraphics` at the end.)

This uses [dvips](http://www.tug.org/texinfohtml/dvips.html) about which there is extensive documentation. Should you want a PDF, you can just complete the above steps with `ps2pdf`.

Comment: And the file needs to be in ps or eps format right? thank you

Comment: @Niroshan Yep, because of [bounding box](http://online.redwoods.cc.ca.us/instruct/darnold/StaffDev/Tips/tip10.pdf); `eps` is generally fine (IMO).

Comment: (For very new latex users) word "file" in my previous comment - I am referring to the image file